# Select always returns 1 record

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have a table for groups where every each is flaged, in column is_active either with 0 or 1. My problem is to select all groups where flag is 1, and the thing is, if I have 0 records with 1, works fine, if I have 1 record with 1, works fine, but if more than one is tagged with 1 it always returns only 1 record, one with the smallest id.
Here are the codes:

```
        String query = "SELECT _id FROM groups WHERE is_active = ?";
        String[] args = { "1" };
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, args);

        if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.v("t", "foo");
            return null;
        } else {
            int count = c.getColumnCount();
            String[] ids = new String[count];
            Log.v("t", "aktywnych group: ------ " + count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                c.moveToPosition(i);
                ids[i] = String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            }
            return ids;

        }
```

What you see now is just another try, I have tried many different ways to obtain this data, never works. 
If you have any ideas how can I fix it I would be greatfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your using this :

```
int count = c.getColumnCount();
```

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnCount%28%29), this method returns the number of COLUMNS of your request. Seeing your query, your asking for only one column : `_id`. So the result will always be 1, or 0 if it find nothing.

You should use this line instead :

```
int count = c.getCount();
```

Comment: @RobertDzieza, Give Googler good notice by accept and upvote answer if it solved your problem. :) . +1 for nice catch.